# jQuery slideToggle goes crazy - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to search the Internet for the solution, but I haven't really found anything helpful.

I'm building a TwitchTV app (FreeCodeCamp challenge) and I want to make something like that: if the status is online (.online), I can click on it and a panel (.slide) with streaming info will slide down, then up if I click again.

(EDIT:

To clarify: I have a few elements with the same class but want to target only the sibling of the one I click.)

The problem is, slideToggle goes up and down a few times (the number is different depending on the element), and I don't really know why. I can only guess it has something to do with classes and next():

```
$(".online").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next(".slide").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Can you help a bit? What causes this panel to slide up and down like crazy? Do you have some tips on how to make this work?

My codepen is https://codepen.io/Strzesia/pen/PJVjbR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used `$(this).nextUntil('.slide').next().slideToggle("slow");`

```js
$(".online").on("click", function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.slide').next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.slide{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:pink;margin:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="online">click</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="slide"></div>

<div class="online">click</div>
<div></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
```

Comment: It would maybe work in different circumstances, but the problem is, I have a few elements with "online" class and the same number of elements with "slide" class. No matter if I use next() or nextAll(), the "slide" element slides up and down and over again.

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with my code, as your answer works here, but not on my codepen. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: If my answer was helpful. Please confirm

Comment: Yes, it was, thank you! :) I need to rewrite my code to make it work, though, the problem was that this part was in a for loop, I think.